# Lines of code not to change during staging / development merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, merge

I currently have a server I deploy Rails apps to via Capistrano and Passenger. I deploy via a Github repo with two branches development and staging.

When merging the staging branch to the master (development) there are certain files such as the database.yml, mailers and other things are different that I don't want to be merged with master - I just want the master files to be kept.

I have found a solution that works quite well that is:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

on the files I don't want changed - however I recently noticed my dev site was being indexed by google so I want to add:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

to the layout to stop indexing on the dev site and obviously I don't want that on the live site so the git assume unchanged will work, however this means any additional changes that do need to be pushed to master on the layout file will be ignored because of assume unchanged.

I was just wondering the best work flow for merging staging branches with development for my situation.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your noindex setting in your layout but only output it if the enviroment is not production:

```
<%= '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">' unless Rails.env == 'production' %>
```

That way you wont have to worry about merging